# Get Distnct items from a group of 2 tables

Tags: linq-to-sql

### tableOwner:

Id: (Primary key)
Name

### TableItems:

Id (Primary Key)
Name:
Description:
ReportingOwner:  [ foreign key with Owner table)

### MappedItems:

Id: (Primary Key)
ItemId: (foreignKey with TableItems)
OwnerId:(foreign key with Owner)

I have 3 tables and i want to fetch list of items in TableItems that are not in MappedItems for a specific Owner.
How can i write LinqToSql query for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var owner="Owner";
var result= 
(
    from item in db.TableItems
    where
    !(
        from mapped in db.MappedItems
        join owner in db.tableOwner
            on mapped.OwnerId equals owner.Id
        where owner.Name==owner
        select mapped.ItemId
    ).Contains(item.Id)
    select item
).ToList();
```

Where `db` is the linq data context